# Using ./configure a 2nd time in Linux: Do I need to re-input previous options?

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, ubuntu-10.04

I am compiling PHP and PostgreSQL myself. I have got things working fine. There were about 25 options I added (using this method http://vladgh.com/blog/install-nginx-and-php-php-fpm-mysql-and-apc) for the PHP compile.

If I want to add an option to PHP (e.g. pdo) do I need to re-enter those 25 and then enter the line for enabling pg_pdo, or are the previous options stored and I only need to enter the one new option? What I am getting at here is the ./configure method, not help for installing postgres. I don't understand how ./configure works or if it stores it's previous values and can just be added to.

Also, if I am upgrading PostgreSQL, is there even any need to recompile PHP if I am NOT changing options.

I hope this is clear. I have been searching for a day now and just can't seem to make headway. I probably don't know enough about the make process for linux. I am running Ubuntu 10.04LTS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"

> The configure script should write a file named ‘config.status’ which
>   describes which configuration options were specified when the program
>   was last configured. This file should be a shell script which, if run,
>   will recreate the same configuration
>   " *(http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html)*

Using this file (config.status) I can issue a ./configure again and add additional options as needed.

I think this is the best way to know what you configured the first time whilst adding to it.

Comment: How to add options to configure using config.status? Can't understand. Config.status will reconfig with exactly same options.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to reenter them.  The `./configure` command will generate a new set of Makefile options, overwriting the previous one.

Luckily, the previous `./configure` command should still be in your console's history so you can just press the up arrow key to find it.

Assuming your shell is bash on Ubuntu, you can also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and start typing `./configure` to search through your command history. Keep hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to find the right one.

Comment: or else you can search through it with `history | grep configure`

Comment: Unfortunately it was done some time ago, so this is a new terminal. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @tentimes It may still be in your history though! Use @Matthieu's `history | grep configure` suggestion and you may find it.  The bash history is quite long by default

Comment: Previous configure command is also recorded at the config.log file at very top.

Answer (score 2):

`phpinfo()`/`php -i`'s output contains a copy of the full `./configure` line used by that build. You can simply cut/paste and then modify for the rebuild. Assuming your PHP build finished, this is the best way to recreate its configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I recompile postgresql, do I *need* to recompile php or will restarting it do please? Thanks :)

Comment: Only if pg's library files were linked directly into the php binaries. if they're externally loaded, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I normally put ./configure --with-a-lot-of-options-I-dont-want-to-remember plus the make and make install in a shell script. This also allows to insert installation instructions for other packages that are needed (ssl, xml2, ...)

As a result, I get a shell script that can be rerun for an installation on a different machine (which may need even more additional packages :-[ )